# Как быстро сравнить все элементы массива с числом?

Tags: javascript, массивы, перебор

Нужно сравнить каждый элемент массива с числом.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 7];
let A = 2;
```

Нужно что то типа 'если **A** равно хоть одному из элементов массива, то...'

Comment: Да сравнивай последовательно - массив-то поди формально случайный? или имеется некая упорядоченность, способная что-то предсказать и дать материал для оптимизации?

Comment: Вообще, это нужно лишь для части моего кода. Суть общего кода в том, что бы вывести 5 элементов(объектов) с самым большим свойством из массива. Делаю через reduce в цикле. Каждый проход достаёт самое большое число исключая предыдущее. И вот как раз часть кода нужна что бы исключить это предыдущее. Она должна сравнивать равен ли текущий элемент в редьюсере самому большому предыдущему

Comment: А не проще отсортировать массив и в один проход выполнить задачу?

Comment: Было бы супер. Я только учусь. Какими методами это можно сделать? Главная задача - сравнивать свойство 'цена', в каждом объекте массива и по итогу выдать 5 объектов с самой большой ценой

Comment: [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выше сказал [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina) нужно было осортировать массив.

Загуглил "методы быстрой сортировки массивов js" и всё встало на свои маста. А после можно спокойно работать с отсортированным, по нужным ключам, массивом.

Вопрос закрыт :)

Comment: Можно ещё использовать `if( arr.includes(2) ) { ... } `

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 7];
let A = 2;

for (i = 0; i != -1; i++) {
  if (arr[i] === A) {
    //Сюда вводите действие
    console.log("Элемент: " + arr[i] + " равен " + A);
    break;
  };
};
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]